# Swift: Using multiple CodingKey types for the same Encodable struct

Tags: ios, swift, codable, encodable

I'm struggling to write a single function that encodes the following struct:

```
struct Lookup: Encodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    
    enum StateCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "stateId"
        case name = "stateName"
    }
    
    enum CityCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "cityId"
        case name = "cityName"
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder, type: StateCodingKeys.Type) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: type)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
      }
}
```

the custom `encode` function here takes `StateCodingKeys.Type` as a parameter, but I can't find a way to let this function accept any `CodingKey` type, like the `CityCodingKeys` enum, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Are you implementing a separate `encode(to:)` method that is not shown? Because the generated `Encodable` conformance is not going to call your `encode(to:type:)` method.

Comment: No, I will just call: `lookUpObj.encode(to:type:)` when I encode the object `lookupObj`

Comment: Well, that works too :) In that case you don't actually need to conform to `Encodable`, and I would argue that you *should* not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a common protocol for both of your enums, add the enum cases you need as `static var`s, and conform the enums to the protocol.

```
protocol LookupCodingKey: CodingKey {
    static var id: Self { get }
    static var name: Self { get }
}
```

```
enum StateCodingKeys: String, LookupCodingKey {
    case id = "stateId"
    case name = "stateName"
}

enum CityCodingKeys: String, LookupCodingKey {
    case id = "cityId"
    case name = "cityName"
}
```

Then you can add the protocol as a generic constraint:

```
func encode<CodingKeyType: LookupCodingKey>(to encoder: Encoder, type: CodingKeyType.Type) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: type)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
}
```

Side note:

If you just want to call `encode(to:type:)` directly to encode a `Lookup`, I would suggest that you do not conform to `Encodable`, since `Lookup` would have a generated `encode(to:)` method, that does not call your `encode(to:type:)`.

When you accidentally pass `Lookup` to something that expects an `Encodable`, and that something encodes it using `encode(to:)`, it will have the unexpected keys `id` and `name`.

I haven't tried, but you might be able to conform to `EncodableWithConfiguration` instead, with the configuration being the type of the coding key.